# FPDF script to pull data from array rather than the generated example

Tags: php, fpdf

Please can someone help me modify this script?

http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script3.php

rather than using a random word generater, I would like to have it pull data from a csv file. At the moment, I have got the data from the csv into a $data using:

```
function LoadData($file)
{
    // Read file lines
    $lines = file($file);
    $data = array();
    foreach($lines as $line)
        $data[] = explode('|',trim($line));
    return $data;
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using

```
    // Your data:
foreach($data as $row)
pdf->Row(array(GenerateItem1($row[0]),GenerateItem1($row[1]),GenerateItem1($ro    w[2]),GenerateItem1($row[3])));
```

and then creating the method

```
function GenerateItem1($row)
{
$gi='';
$gi = $row;
    return $gi;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just feed FPDF your data.  From the example page:

```
$pdf=new PDF_MC_Table();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',14);
//Table with 20 rows and 4 columns
$pdf->SetWidths(array(30,50,30,40));
srand(microtime()*1000000);  <-- This line can go away now too

// Replace this next block with your data.  Example data:
for($i=0;$i<20;$i++)
    $pdf->Row(array(GenerateSentence(),GenerateSentence(),GenerateSentence(),GenerateSentence()));


// Your data:
foreach($data as $entry)
    $pdf->Row($data);

$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: Thank you for coming back. Unfortunately I get the following Warning: strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /public_html/pdfphp/mc_table.php on line 76

Comment: My csv has 12 columns, and 13 rows (although obviously the number of rows can change)